# What is the difference between mat-select and select in angular

Tags: angular, angular-material

I want to know what is the difference between mat-select and select, and why do you use mat-select over select.

I have searched the documentation online but can only find the documentation for angular on mat-select and select.

Answer (score 1):

`mat-select` is Angular Material Design (gives you enhanced material based style/ design) form control and `select` is native HTML element. `mat-select` has properties and methods to use instead of writing your own for `select` native element.

https://material.angular.io/components/select/overview

Comment: I guess the main difference and a good reason to use the `material` design is that has been designed specifically so that its components can be used over web-, mobile and desktop without lots of configuration?

Answer (score 0):

**`<mat-select>`** is a form control for selecting a value from a set of options, similar to the native **`<select>`** element.

The differentiator between those 2 is Mat denotes Material Design. You can read more about selects in the **[`Material`](https://material.angular.io/components/select/overview)** Design